# Agregar columna a partir de los valores de las filas en SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado que realiza la búsqueda de un cliente por `idCliente` y muestra el importe pagado de cada una de sus cuentas de acuerdo a cada periodo, los cuales son creados por un PIVOT, cuya finalidad es otorgarle un crédito al cliente si este tiene más de 5 pagos otorgados en cada una de sus cuentas:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[px_clientePuntual]
    @idCliente AS VARCHAR (MAX)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);

SET @sql = N'
 SELECT *
  
  FROM
  (  
    SELECT 

        pp.cuenta,
        mc.periodo,
        mc.importePagado,
        CASE WHEN (pp.pagoPuntual <= 5) THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END AS CuentaValida

        FROM

        movimientosCliente mc WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN cliente c WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.idCliente = mc.idCliente
        LEFT OUTER JOIN pagos pp WITH (NOLOCK) ON pp.idMovimiento = mc.idMovimiento
        WHERE c.idCliente = @idCliente

  ) AS T1
  PIVOT   
  (
  SUM(importePagado)
  FOR periodo IN (' + (SELECT STUFF(
 (
 SELECT
   ',' + QUOTENAME(LTRIM(periodo))
 FROM
   (
            SELECT DISTINCT
            p.periodo
            FROM
            dbo.periodos p
            
   ) AS T2
 ORDER BY
 periodo
 FOR XML PATH('')
 ), 1, 1, ''))+ N')
  ) AS P;' ;
 
 EXEC (@sql) ;
 
 END
```

**Hasta ahora llevo lo siguiente:**
Ejemplo 1

[image: Avance actual]

Ejemplo 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero necesito **agregar una columna adicional (`OtorgaCredito`)** donde envíe 0 ó 1, según los resultados de la columna CuentaValida: 1, si Todas sus cuentas son validas (1). 0, si todas o alguna de sus cuentas no son validas(0).

**Para el caso del Ejemplo 1 debería verse así**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ejemplo 2:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué inconveniente tienes para lograrlo?

Comment: @jachguate, intenté que esta consulta fuera una subconsulta, y en la selección general llamar todos mis campos y hacer la validación desde allí, es lo único que se me ha ocurrido, pero me manda errores, la verdad no sé como poder validar todas las cuentas

Comment: ¿en serio esto corre en mysql? quién lo diría, mi bola de cristal dice que la sintaxis tiene toda la pinta de sql-server...

Comment: Es correcto, SQL-Server

Comment: El asunto es que así como la publicaste, parece una solicitud apropiada para un sitio de contratación de programadores, pero no para StackOverflow. Toda la descripción viene bien para entender el problema, pero aquí la ayuda parte de resolver el problema que tengas sobre la marcha, intentando solucionarlo por ti misma. Sugiero que comiences por editar las etiquetas y darte una vuelta por [ask]. Un saludo.

Comment: Te daré una idea, yo lo que haría sería usar una tabla temporal con el resultado que ya muestras en el EJEMPLO 1 y 2, contaría los registros de la tabla, haría una sumatoria del campo CuentaValida y por ultimo comparo si la sumatoria es igual al numero de registros quiere decir que el resultado es 1 de lo contrario es 0, actualizo mi tabla y listo tengo el resultado final con un select *from de la tabla temporal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo creo que una solución a tu consulta seria insertar los datos en una tabla temporal y al final hacer otra vez la consulta pero ya con los datos finales y la validación adicional que requieres.

Todo esto dentro de tu misma consulta dinámica, te dejo un ejemplo de como lo aplicaría yo en tu caso.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[px_clientePuntual]
    @idCliente AS VARCHAR (MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);
    /*Como se usara en mas de una ocasión, mejor lo dejo en una variable*/
    DECLARE @COLUMNAS AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT STUFF((
                        SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(LTRIM(periodo))
                        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT p.periodo FROM dbo.periodos p ) AS T2
                        ORDER BY periodo FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, ''));

    SET @sql = N'
        SELECT *
        INTO #TMP1 -- aquí debería de insertar todo el resultado que tienes ahorita en una tabla temporal
        FROM
        (  
            SELECT  pp.cuenta,
                mc.periodo,
                mc.importePagado,
                CASE WHEN (pp.pagoPuntual <= 5) THEN 1  ELSE 0  END AS CuentaValida
            FROM movimientosCliente mc WITH (NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN cliente c WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.idCliente = mc.idCliente
                LEFT OUTER JOIN pagos pp WITH (NOLOCK) ON pp.idMovimiento = mc.idMovimiento
            WHERE c.idCliente = @idCliente
        ) AS T1
        PIVOT   
        (
            SUM(importePagado)
            FOR periodo IN (' +  @COLUMNAS + N')
        ) AS P;

       /*Una ves teniendo los datos en la tabla temporal, hacemos la final, y agrupo los datos para tu validación*/
        SELECT T1,cuenta,
            T2.periodo,
            T3.case when X.CuentaValida = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OtorgaCredito,
            '  + @COLUMNAS + N'
        FROM #TMP1 T1
            INNER JOIN (
                /*Uso el min, por que en teoría si todos son correctos regresara 1 en caso contrario será 0*/
                SELECT T2.cuenta, MIN(CuentaValida) CuentaValida 
                FROM #TMP1 T2
                GROUP BY T2.cuenta
            ) X ON X.cuenta = T1.cuenta
    ';

    EXEC (@sql);

END
```

Comment: Gracias, hice una pequeña modificación en el último INNER JOIN (X) reemplazando cuenta por idCliente, para que agrupara por cliente, en seguida lo actualizo en mi pregunta, con tu solución propuesta, complementado con la propuesta de @jachguate

Answer (score 1):

Puedes valerte de almacenar el resultado en una tabla temporal, llenar dicha tabla con los resultados de la primera consulta y luego llenar la columna dependiendo del resultado final.

Dado que tu consulta es compleja, hagamos un par de ejemplos para que comprendas la idea y ya tu adaptas el código a tu situación particular.

Primero, voy a crear y a llenar una tabla `Muestra` que simula contener el resultado básico de la consulta que ejecutas actualmente (sin las columnas de pivote, que no hacen falta para el cálculo).

```
create table Muestra (
  idCliente     int
, Cuenta        int
, CuentaValida  bit
)
;

insert into Muestra 
values (1, 1001, 1)
     , (1, 1002, 1)
     , (1, 1003, 1)
     , (2, 2001, 1)
     , (2, 2002, 0)
     , (2, 2003, 1)
;
```

Ahora, creamos un procedimiento almacenado que hace el trabajo básico:

```
create procedure Reporte(@idCliente int)
as 
begin
  if object_id('tempdb..#TemporalReporte', 'U') is not null drop table #TemporalReporte;

  select Cuenta, CuentaValida, cast (null as bit) OtorgaCredito
    into #TemporalReporte
    from Muestra
   where idCliente = @idCliente;

  if exists (select 1 from #TemporalReporte where CuentaValida = 0)
    update #TemporalReporte set OtorgaCredito = 0
  else
    update #TemporalReporte set OtorgaCredito = 1

  select *
    from #TemporalReporte;
end
go
```

Inicia eliminando la tabla temporal. Luego crea una nueva tabla con el resultado de de la tabla `Muestra` para el cliente que se ha pasado como parámetro, lo cual simula tu proceso actual de obtención de datos.

En esta consulta, añadimos una columna, originalmente vacía, de tipo `bit` y con nombre `OtorgaCredito`, de tal manera que esté situada donde la queremos en el resutlado. Más adelante la vamos a llenar con los datos adecuados.

Crear una nueva tabla temporal en cada ejecución es crítico para tu proceso, dado que al crear el procedimineto almacenado desconoces cuantas y cuales serán las columnas que devolverá la consulta en cada ejecución.

Por otro lado, filtramos por cliente para probar con uno que si tiene crédito y uno que no.

Luego, después, llenamos la columna `OtorgaCredito`. Acá la lógica es, si existe al menos un registro con `CuentaValida = 0`, ponerle 0 y si no 1.

Finalmente, seleccionamos todos los datos de la tabla temporal para devolver el resultado.

Ahora probamos:

```
exec Reporte 1;
exec Reporte 2;
```

Devuelve:

```
Cuenta      CuentaValida OtorgaCredito
----------- ------------ -------------
1001        1            1
1002        1            1
1003        1            1

Cuenta      CuentaValida OtorgaCredito
----------- ------------ -------------
2001        1            0
2002        0            0
2003        1            0
```

Bien, aquí terminamos con el concepto para devolver la nueva columna con los valores que quires, pero te ayudaré con otra vuelta de tuerca, ya que actualmente tienes la sentencia que llena la tabla en una variable de texto, por lo que voy a cambiar el SP para que ejecute también SQL dinámico para dar vida a la tabla.

```
create procedure Reporte(@idCliente int)
as 
begin
  if object_id('tempdb..##TemporalReporte', 'U') is not null drop table ##TemporalReporte;

  declare @sql nvarchar(max);
  declare @sql2 nvarchar(max);
  set @sql = N'
  select Cuenta, CuentaValida, cast (null as bit) OtorgaCredito
    from Muestra
   where idCliente = ' + cast(@idCliente as varchar) + '
  ';

  set @sql2 = 'select * into ##TemporalReporte from (' + @sql + ') q1' ;

  execute sp_executesql @stmt = @sql2;

  if exists (select 1 from ##TemporalReporte where CuentaValida = 0)
    update ##TemporalReporte set OtorgaCredito = 0
  else
    update ##TemporalReporte set OtorgaCredito = 1

  select *
    from ##TemporalReporte;
end
go
```

La lógica de este último procedimiento es la misma del anterior, pero he trasladado la primera consulta a una variable @sql, luego he preparado otra variable @sql2 que contiene una sentencia para ejecutar la primera consulta y almacenar el resultado completo en `##TemporalRepote`.

OJO, que he *actualizado* la tabla temporal que usaba anteriormente a un doble `##`. Esta es una tabla temporal que es compartida entre todas las sesiones y es que, de no hacerlo de esa manera, no tendría acceso a la tabla temporal creada dentro de la ejecución dinámica fuera de ella.

Tiene el inconveniente que es compartida entre todas las sesiones del servidor y eso podría dar problemas de concurrencia. Puedes, sin embargo crear nombres de tablas en base a algún consecutivo u otra técnica para evitarlos, en caso que lleguen a presentarse.